# Using AutoMapper, how do I map an aggregate root property to all destination collection item properties?

Tags: .net, .net-core, automapper

I have created an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is located and available [here](https://github.com/jstallm/AutomapperListIssue-MRE)

In summary, I want to map a property of a Source class to a property of multiple list items of a Destination property (which is of type list)

Here is the example from the MRE

Source

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class OuterSource
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public List<OuterSourceListItem> List { get; set; }

        public string OuterSourceProp1 { get; set; }// Notice how you can have prop on source which is not on dest, no complaints from AutoMapper there
    }
    public class OuterSourceListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Desc { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Destination

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class OuterDest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public List<OuterDestListItem> List { get; set; }
    }
    public class OuterDestListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Desc { get; set; }

        public int MyParentID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Mapper configuration

```
    return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new OuterSourceToOuterDest());
        cfg.AddProfile(new OuterSourceListItemToOuterDestListItem());
    });
```

Profile

```
public class OuterSourceListItemToOuterDestListItem : Profile
{
    public OuterSourceListItemToOuterDestListItem()
    {
        CreateMap<OuterSourceListItem, OuterDestListItem>();
    }
}



  public class OuterSourceToOuterDest : Profile
    {
        public OuterSourceToOuterDest()
        {
            CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
        }
    }
```

With the above setup, here is the client making use of those classes, including the actual mapping

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var inputModel = new OuterSource() { ID = 1};
    inputModel.List = new List<OuterSourceListItem>();
    inputModel.List.Add(new OuterSourceListItem() { Name = "aaa", Desc = "dddd" });
    var domain = _mapper.Map<OuterDest>(inputModel);

    return Ok(domain);
}
```

The actual output now is on the left in red below, the desired result is green on the right
[image]

I need the list.myParentID value to be equal to the value for OuterSource.ID
which you can see here
[image]

Its almost like I need to somehow derive the MyParentID somehow in property setters/getters within OuterDest?

Comment: Your question is confusing, please could you clarify it a bit? For example by showing an input model and an output model, with comments indicating how the properties on the output model should be populated from the input?

Comment: @IanKemp, all of this is located within the MRE provided above , here is the link https://github.com/jstallm/AutomapperListIssue-MRE Can you take a look at this code?

Comment: @IanKemp, Ive updated the entire question, and also greatly simplified the MRE in the github repo. Please let me know if you can take a look. The code should be very clean and clear to understand now with this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is just to invoke a method on the OuterDest instance right after the mapping using the method

AfterMap(Action<TSource, TDestination> afterFunction)

> Execute a custom function to the source and/or destination types after
> member mapping

[image]

[image]